# MongoDB poor performance few hours after data deletion

Tags: mongodb

I've got 3 Mongo DB (v 3.4.10) servers (256 Gb RAM, 1 Tb HDD, 12 CPUs each) as a replica setup. Servers are under decent load and HDD is eaten up quite rapidly. I'm considering sharding big collections, but not yet there.

In the meantime, the typical scenario I face:

1. Morning I see an alert that database HDD is 92% used
2. Midday I delete bunch of redundant data from big collections (1M - 4M entries) on master. I either update collection like this:

   update({}, {'$unset' : {'key_1' : true, 'key_2' : true, 'key_3' : true}}, {"multi" : 1})

or create new collection, insert only needed data there and drop old one.

3. Evening (about 4-5 hours after deletion, usually peak of the load) Mongo response time increases dramatically from 3-4ms to 500ms. This period lasts for a while, during which my application is almost down. It only restores back to normal performance after I stop my application completely for 10-20 minutes and try to start it back again.

The days I do not delete data - database performs like normal.

I read a bit about oplog and nuances of deleting data on replicated servers. However, in my case the lag between deletion and performance drop is several hours.

Is there any internal Mongo process, which happens hours after massive update/insert? How should I bulk update/insert to avoid this?